# One to Many, but Identifying One of the Many as the 'Default'

Tags: database-design

I have a tables *Person* and *Address*.  A *Person* can have multiple *Address* records, so a simple 1..* relationship with *Address* having a field referencing 'Person ID'.

Now, for a given *Person* I wish to identify their 'default' or 'primary' *Address*.

I've came up with two ideas, but I'm not convinced about either.  Before I decide, can anyone offer any comments with regards to potential issues I could face down the line with either option...

(a). Could have a 'Default Address ID' on *Person* which would store the
    ID of the default *Address* record.  Possible pitfall here is that
    an *Address* not belonging to this *Person* could be set here, so
    would need an additional check constraint to prevent this.

(b). Could have a 'Default' flag on the *Address* table, but this has the
    possibility of allowing multiple selections, so would need further
    checks so that when setting the flag, it is also cleared on all
    records belonging to the same *Person*.

Any

Comment: So far, I'm leaning towards the (b)-type solutions below, but I notice this does not offer a obvious way to enforce that a User must have at least 1 address which would be desirable.

With (a), it's just a case of making the 'Default Address ID' not null.

Comment: If you go with (a) and make the 'Default Address ID' not null, you'll have serious troubles inserting and deleting from the 2 tables. Circular paths in tables references is no joy.

Comment: I agree, but is there a better alternative to ensure the a person has at least 1 address?

Comment: Use a normal `1:n` relationship between Person and Address and ensure via transactions/stored procedures that all inserts/deletes/updates in the 2 tables keep this constraint. (or with 3 tables, similarly, that all persons have at least one address and exactly 1 default address)

Comment: DDL statements define `1::0..n` and `1::0..1` relationships. Making them strict `1::1..n` or `1::1` cannot be done by DDL alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with (B) and then safeguard the setting of the default bit.

From reading your comments on your question I want to add that to enforce that there is always at least 1 address set with the default bit you just need to handle that in your stored procedure.

Something like:

for an insert:

```
DECLARE @IsDefault bit;
SET @IsDefault = 0;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from tblAddresses WHERE PersonID = @PersonID And Default = 1)
BEGIN
   SET @IsDefault = 1;
END

INSERT INTO tblAddress (.... Default ... )
       VALUES (... @IsDefault ... );
```

for an update:

```
IF (@Default = 1)
BEGIN
   Update tblAddress
   SET
   tblAddress.Default = 0
   FROM tblAddress
   WHERE tblAddress.PersonID = @PersonID;

   Update tblAddress
   SET
   tblAddress.Default = 1
   WHERE ID = @AddressID;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblAddresses WHERE PersonID = @PersonID AND Default = 1 AND AddressID != @AddressID)
   BEGIN
      UPDATE tblAddresses 
      SET Default = 0
      WHERE AddressID = @AddressID;
   END
END
```

In addition, you could prevent this from your user interface as well, but it doesn't hurt to have an extra layer of protection in the DB.

Comment: This is pretty much the solution I've gone with.  I think the problems I was having were that I was trying to enforce every possible requirement in DDL, which was resulting in a schema that was fast becoming unmanageable.  I think I've learned a far more important lesson from this post than the original question that I asked.

Comment: @Gavin This is easily enforceable at the DB layer with a constraint.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is (normalizing the data by) adding another table `DefaultAddress`:

```
Person
------
PersonId
... other stuff
PRIMARY KEY (PersonId)

Address
-------
AddressId
PersonId 
... other stuff
PRIMARY KEY (AddressId)
FOREIGN KEY (PersonId)
  REFERENCES Person(PersonId)

DefaultAddress
--------------
AddressId
PersonId 
PRIMARY KEY (AddressId)
UNIQUE KEY (PersonId)           --- every person has (max) one default address
FOREIGN KEY (PersonId, AddressId)
  REFERENCES Address(PersonId, AddressId)
```

Comment: This has a problem where a row in table `Address` exists, but the corresponding row in `DefaultAddress` does not.

Comment: @Dal, the idea is that the `DefaultAddress` is populated with data from (one row from) `Address`.

Answer (score 0):

Option (a) - storing a reference to an address as a default address could cause an issue if you ever change the values for the default address.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but not sure I understand.  Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I could go with a subset of B, I would add an `AddressType` field to the Address table where you could define Primary and Secondary or some generic type, then you also set yourself up for future types of addresses without having to modify the schema.

Answer (score 0):

We have a default flag field and a trigger that makes sure that one and only one record has the default value of 1. Make sure to write the trigger to handle multiple record inserts/updates and deletes and test them. So if it is the first record inserted, then the field automatically gets set to 1. If the record with the field set to one is deleted, we havea a business rule inteh trigger which determines which remaining record will get the default. If a different record is updated to 1, then the existing record that has the 1 is updated to have 0 in the field. If you don't use a trigger, it is highly likely you will have data integrity problmes at some point.

Comment: I have had a ton of scalablility issues with triggers. Is there some special way you do them to avoid this? I have instead, had to do this as I did in my answer. However, I would love for you to prove me wrong on this, because I love triggers.

Comment: Badly written triggers can have scalibilty issues particularly if someone choses to process one record at a time instead of in sets or updates records that don't need updating, etc. (I once was involved in fixing a trigger that handled multiple record inserts through a cursor, changing it to a set-based trigger improved performance from 45 mins to 40 secs for a 40K record insert). Triggers need to be highly optimized for performance because they will add a time to every action. They also need to be thoroughly tested to make sure that any kind of action on the table can be properly handled.

Answer (score 0):

instead of
*(a) could have a 'Default Address ID' on Person*
how about a boolean?
isDefaultAddr

To explain further, instead of having a field like defaultAddressID in the Person table, you could just have a boolean field in the Person table, like isDefaultAddress.  Its value is true if this is the default address for that person, otherwise, false.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but not sure I understand your suggestion. Could you explain further?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for option B with UNIQUE index on `Address` table including `personId` and `default` flag but only for rows where `default = true`. Something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX address_default ON address (personId, default) WHERE (default = true);
```

This way you assure that there are no more that one default address for a person.

If it happens that none address is default, choose the first one.